# Проверить начинается ли строка со слов

Tags: delphi, строки

Доброго времени суток. Нужно проверить начинается ли строка со слов "Работа в интернет?" ,если да то нужно удалить из строки  первые 3 слова, т. е. нужно удалить именно это словосочетание "работа в интернет". Пока решил вторую часть задачи.т.е удаление всех символов до знака "?"

```
    procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject); 
var s , n , text: String; position: Integer;

    begin 
text:=Edit1.Text; 
position := pos('?', Edit1.Text); If position <> 0 then 
S := copy(Edit1.Text, position, length(Edit1.Text) - position + 1);
    end;
```

но вот как проверить начинается ли строка со слов "Работа в интернет?" или там другой вопрос не соображу..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure DeleteSome(var s: string; some: string);
var
 k: integer;
begin
 k:=pos(some,s);
 if k>0 then
  delete(s,k,length(some));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Edit1.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  find:string;
  s:string;
  i:integer;
begin
  find:='Работа в интернет';

  // Идем в цикле по всему списку
  For i:=0 to ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
  // Ищем совпадение по фразе 'Работа в интернет'
    If Pos(find, ListBox1.Items.Text)<>0
    Then
    Begin
  // Загружаем текст из списка в string
      s:=Listbox1.Items.Text;
  // Удаляем нужный текст из string
      DeleteSome(s,find);
  // Загружаем текст обратно в список    
      Listbox1.Items.Text:=s;
    end;
end;
end.
```

Если смысл именно в том, как проверить на начало строки, то StrUtils unit есть AnsiStartsStr - http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/AnsiStartsStr.php.html

Comment: спасибо,все работает!

Answer (score 5):

```
k := Pos(find, ListBox1.Items.Text);
if k = 1 then //совпадение с первого символа
begin
  Listbox1.Items.Text := Copy(Listbox1.Items.Text, k + Length(find), Length(Listbox1.Items.Text));
end;
```

Незачем 2 раза искать в строке одно и тоже. И можно обойтись без временной переменной. Можно в количество символов для копирования добавить `-Length(find)`, но не обязательно. Будет скопировано столько символов, сколько указано, или пока не закончится строка.